# Compare range of time and compute for time difference

Tags: php, mysql, time

I wanted to determine whether the given datetime values falls within the range of time and then insert in the database the time difference between $actual_dateOut and $range_dateOut.

example of data:

```
$actual_dateIn  = "2013-06-01 06:54:00" 
$actual_dateOut = "2013-06-01 19:20:00"

$range_dateIn     = "08:00:00"
$range_dateOut    = "18:00:00"
```

here is what I have done so far:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
 $dateIn  =  date($actual_dateIn, time());
 $dateOut =  date($actual_dateOut, time());


 if($dateIn <= strtotime($range_dateIn) && $dateOut <= strtotime($range_dateOut))
 {
    $ot = $range_dateOut->diff($strtotime($actual_dateOut));
    $hours = $ot->h;


    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_ot (id, fDate, shiftCode, ot ) 
                   VALUES ('$id', '$actual_dateIn', '$shift', '$hours')";

    $result_ot = mysql_query($sql_insert);  
 }
```

but it doesn't compute for the difference between $actual_dateOut and $range_dateOut.

Comment: the first I see is that you should not do $strtotime(... remove the $

Comment: i already did and i have tried  $dateIn = explode(" ", $actual_dateIn); $dateIn = $dateIn[1]; to get the time only in $actual_dateIn but still no luck

Comment: if you do strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2) then you have the difference in milliseconds. so do result / (1000 * 60 * 60) to get the hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it next way (checked):
Attention:
1. $shift is empty in this code.
2. You need to decide how to convert time_difference in seconds to hours

```
$actual_dateIn  = "2013-06-01 06:54:00";
$actual_in_arr = explode(' ', $actual_dateIn);

$actual_dateOut = "2013-06-01 17:20:00";
$actual_out_arr = explode(' ', $actual_dateOut);

$actual_in_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$actual_in_arr[1]);
$actual_out_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$actual_out_arr[1]);

$range_dateIn     = "08:00:00";
$range_dateOut    = "18:00:00";
$range_in_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$range_dateIn);
$range_out_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$range_dateOut);

 if($actual_in_time <= $range_in_time && $actual_out_time <= $range_out_time)
 {   
    $time_difference = $range_out_time - $actual_out_time;
    $hours = round( $time_difference/60/60, 2 );
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_ot (id, fDate, shiftCode, ot ) 
                   VALUES ('$id', '$actual_dateIn', '$shift', '$hours')";
    $result_ot = mysql_query($sql_insert);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a few problems

1) The date() function takes an input of a date format, and an optional unix timestamp.  You are passing in a datetime.

2) Your if() condition is comparing a non-numeric string with an integer returned from strtotime().

3) Date returns a string, not an object, you are going to get a fatal from calling the diff() method on a non object.

4) You need to remove the $ before $strtotime($actual_dateOut)

All that being said.. I would just go ahead and convert all 4 to unix timestamps.
The datetimes run strtotime() on.  For the range values, explode on the colon, update the value of each index.  Multiply index 0 by 3600, index 1 by 60, and leave the third alone.  And then run array_sum() on the variable for the exploded array.

At that point you can use simple comparisons on the variables, and subtract to find the difference.